# Is "details" singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. Here is the details you requested.
> 2. Here are the details you requested.

Having googled ["Here is the details"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22here%20is%20the%20details%22) and ["Here are the details"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22here%20are%20the%20details%22), I've got 18m+ results for the former and 11m+ results for the latter.

Comment: I don't think that this is a question of details being plural, but more of the usage of `here is` vs. `here are`. Google `here is/are the things` with similar results you had.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Grammar

---

- "Details" is plural. "[Detail](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/details)" is singular.
- In sentences like "here [to be] [something]", [to be] is the verb and [something] is the subject.  [The words there and here are never subjects.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)
- The verb has to agree with its
  subject. [A singular subject takes a singular verb and a plural subject takes a plural verb](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp).

Therefore, "**Here are the details you requested**" is the correct one.

### Usage

---

As noted by Colin Fine and  Kosmonaut in their comments below and by Piet Delport in his answer, "here is [plural]" is commonly used in casual English. Maybe it is more used than the grammatical form where the subject agrees with the verb (to be confirmed). Refer to [Piet Deport's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/is-details-singular/3681#3681) for a possible explanation.

Comment: If only language were so simple that you could just say "This is correct" and that was the end of the matter. The fact is that, as Ralph indicated, many people use "here is" and even more often "there's" irrespective of the number of the complement.

Comment: @Colin Fine - my understanding is that the question is on what is "grammatically" correct. I don't know much about the actual usage. I did check quickly some of the google results for "here is the details" and found out that most of them for some reason did not include that exact phrase. So I'm not sure that "here is the details" is more used than "here are the details".

Comment: I think Colin Fine's point is useful in addition to the main answer, because it helps explain why someone might read and hear the "wrong" answer repeatedly.  I probably use "here's" and "there's" most of the time in casual speech, regardless of the verb agreement (— I'm from the US, if that matters).  I think you'd see it sometimes in casual written English, and all over the place in spoken English.

Answer (score 1):

Ralph Rickenbach is right: this question is not really about *"details"*, but about the phrase *"Here is ..."*.

*"Details"* is definitely plural: you'll say *"The details are ..."*, never  *"The details is ..."*.

*"Here is ..."*, on the other hand, is very closely associated with the contraction *"Here's ..."*, and is commonly used even with normal plurals (instead of the cumbersome *"Here're ..."*):

- *"Here's the [details/things/people/objects/...] you want."*

Comment: "There're" would be as weird as "here're" and yet you don't say "there's things that you didn't consider" but "there are things that you didn't consider".

Comment: Actually, people do, for the same reasons: compare the Google-count of ["there's things"](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=%22there's+things%22) (114,000) with ["there're things"](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=%22there're+things%22) (31,900).

Comment: This comparison doesn't mean much, does it? Most people would write "there are" instead of "there're". Google-count for "there are things" is over 8 millions.

Comment: I know, i'm just pointing out the effect that the ease of contraction has on *is* versus *are*.

Answer (score 0):

Say them to yourself and see if they sound correct to you.

To me, *here are the details you requested* will always sound "correct". I might say *here's the details you requested* conversationally or in an informal setting, but I can't see *Here is the details you requested* ever being right.